# Python parse table

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, beautifulsoup

I have the table parsed with this code

```
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find("table", attrs={"class":"table table-condensed table-bordered"})

datasets = []
for row in table.find_all("tr")[1:]:
    dataset = (td.get_text() for td in row.find_all("td"))
    print (tuple(dataset))
    datasets.append(dataset)
print("___________________________________\n")
print(tuple(dataset))
print("___________________________________\n")
print("parsing\n")
```

it gives

```
('A1 ', '- ', '- ', '- ', '- ', ' -\n ')
('A2', '- ', '- ', '- ', '- ', ' -\n ')
('A3', '- ', '- ', '- ', '- ', ' -\n ')
('A4', ' 1 W ', ' 50.1 Hz ', ' 0 V ', ' 24 Â°C ', ' 2018-09-12 19:05:49\n ')
('A5', ' 1 W ', ' 0 V ')
```

the results datasets is empty

```
 ()
```

I would like to but the results in an Array like so I can access each row/column but 
and find out

```
if datasets[3][0]=='A4' print (datasets[3][2])
```

why if I change the code and deleting the print (tuple(dataset)) the code works better (though it is not as I expected) but I can have a filled datasets and not an empty one as peviously:

```
datasets = []
for row in table.find_all("tr")[1:]:
    #dataset = dict(zip(headings, (td.get_text() for td in row.find_all("td"))))
    dataset = (td.get_text() for td in row.find_all("td"))
    datasets.append(dataset)
    #print (tuple(dataset))

print("___________________________________\n")
print(list(datasets[3]))
print(list(datasets[4]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that this statement:

```
dataset = (td.get_text() for td in row.find_all("td"))
```

returns a generator expression. This is kind of like an iterator, in the sense that, once you iterate through to the end, then you will have consumed the generator. Further access to the generator will not return anything more.

When you print the contents of dataset as a tuple, this consumes the data, so that when you go to append, there is nothing left. Deleting the print statement gets you closer, but you are still working with a generator, and what you want is the actual data.

For now, try changing the line above to:

```
dataset = tuple(td.get_text() for td in row.find_all("td"))
```

Or just change the enclosing ()'s to []'s to make it a list comprehension:

```
dataset = [td.get_text() for td in row.find_all("td")]
```

This will consume the generator expression, but will give you the data values in a tuple or list, which you can access again and again. When you add the dataset tuple to datasets, it will contain the values you are interested in.

Comment: dataset = [td.get_text() for td in row.find_all("td")]   works perfectly, thanks for the explanation